# Find all injections from set $\{1,2,3\}$ into set $\{4,5\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am supposed to find all the injections from set $\{1,2,3\}$ to set $\{4,5\}$. Is it possible to do (meaning are there any injections?)? If so, what are the possible injections?

Comment: Please include in your post what you understand to be the definition of an injection from one set to another.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $f:A\longrightarrow B$ is an injection, then $\:|A|\le |B|$.

Comment: Thanks. And what about the bijection? Is it possible?

Comment: bijection $=$ injection $+$ surjection.

Comment: @J.Doe a bijection is a special kind of injection (*one which is also a surjection*).  If there are no injections, then certainly there are no bijections either.  For finite sets, there exists at least one bijection between two sets if and only if they have the same number of elements.  This extends to infinite sets as well but we have to be careful about what we mean by an infinite set's "number of elements."  Your sets have a different number of elements (*three and two respectively*) and so clearly have no bijections between them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

An injection is a function where each output is mapped to by at most one input. Since it is a function, every input must map to one output. However, you have more inputs than outputs, so it is not possible for each input to map to different outputs (see Pidgeonhole Principle).

Comment: Thanks! and what about the bijection of the same sets?

Comment: A function is such that for each input, the function outputs at most one output.  An injection is such that, for $x, y \in$ the domain of the function,  if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x = y$.

Comment: Thanks, I added that to the answer, and clarified a bit.